# Valgrind complaining about uninitialized values

Tags: c, clang, valgrind, compiler-optimization, c11

I have this little snippet here:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char b[128];

  strcpy(b, "four");

  if(strcmp(b, "seven") == 0) {/* Line 9 */
     printf("buffer 'b' contains \"%s\"\n", b);
  }
  else if(strcmp(b, "four") == 0) {
     printf("buffer 'b' contains \"%s\"\n", b);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with Clang version "7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)" it is all nice and dandy even with `-O3`. If I do the same with Clang version "8.0.0-3~ubuntu18.04.2 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)" or later (checked version 9.0.0, too) with every optimization except `-O0` Valgrind tells me

```
==17979== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17979== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17979== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17979== Command: ./glibc_strcmp_x86_64_sse_4_2_bug
==17979== 
==17979== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17979==    at 0x400540: main (glibc_strcmp_x86_64_sse_4_2_bug.c:9)
==17979==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17979==    at 0x400520: main (glibc_strcmp_x86_64_sse_4_2_bug.c:4)
==17979== 
buffer 'b' contains "four"
==17979== 
==17979== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17979==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17979==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==17979== 
==17979== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17979== 
==17979== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17979== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I initialize the buffer with e.g.: `char b[128] = {0};` it is OK, of course, no complains anymore. Or if I use a local version of `strcmp`.

Dumping the assembly outputs of each `-O1` and `-O0` respectively shows that the optimization of Clang-8 optimizes all occurrences of `strcmp` (and `strcpy`) away. Clang-7 does not do it, it calls all of the functions.

But who is to blame here? Is it a bug in Clang > 7? Or is my assumption wrong that `strcmp`, even if optimized away, should stop once either of the inputs reaches `\0`?

Comment: The alloc and free is from `printf()` via `stdio.h`. The error is evidently a know problem, e.g. `glibc_strcmp_x86_64_sse_4_2_bug.c:9` not your line 9. I suspect there is some test done on the dest parameter `b` to `strcmp()` that is the problem, but you would have to look at `glibc_strcmp_x86_64_sse_4_2_bug.c:9` for further details.

Comment: It is fixed by `clang version 11.0.0` cannot reproduce. Compiled via `clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Ofast -o clang_bug clang_bug.c`

Comment: Note that the current release of Valgrind is 3.16.  Version 3.13 is quite old.  It might be a good idea to upgrade.

Comment: On my system (`clang` v7.0.1 and `valgrind` v3.15.0), I can _not_ reproduce. AFAICT, from desk checking, your program does _not_ [_can_ not] produce a leak [or other error], and reports `0 errors` here. As Johnathan mentioned, your `valgrind` is old. This is probably a bug in `valgrind` (and _not_ a compiler issue)--the final count reported is _wrong_. You _could_ rerun with `-v` [as suggested], but it's a bit of a moot point.

Comment: Same failures for Clang 12.0.0 (took me some time to compile hence  not included in the post). So let's try an up-to-date version of Valgrind (3.16.1)...yepp, @JonathanLeffler that was it. Back to my legacy hell, but at least I can point some fingers now ;-) Thanks to all and if somebody wants some points: just write an answer, I'll stamp it.

Comment: Some implementations of string.h functions will deliberately read past the end of a string, e.g. loading 8 or 16 bytes from memory at a time, then checking to see if the null byte is among them.  This can be done safely if alignment is checked, so that `strcmp` will not touch any page that it otherwise wouldn't, and therefore won't cause a spurious segfault.  But it will get trapped by checkers like valgrind.  For newer compiler/library/valgrind versions, valgrind may know about these false positives and omit them from the report, but you seem to have old versions of stuff.

Comment: @NateEldredge not everyone can afford all of the new and shiny gimmicks ;-) It was one of my first thoughts, too, that it is the `strcmp` implementation itself but Clang optimized all occurrences of `strcmp` away, so that couldn't be it. Main difference between `-O0` and `-O1` is that `-O0` calls `strcmp` but everything higher doesn't anymore. I used several versions of Clang and GCC, even compiled the last stable GlibC to link against! At the end: Valgrind too old, geez! But isn't it always the last key on the keyring that opens the lock? ;-)

Comment: Taking a look at [the assembly generated by clang 8](https://godbolt.org/z/qxKWP3), it's true that it does read from uninitialized memory with `movzx eax, word ptr [rsp + 4]`.  The following conditional jump `je .LBB0_2` does "depend" on that result, except that it really doesn't because it's the result of `or eax, 386075157`, which can never be zero so the jump is never taken.  It's very strange code, and I can't blame valgrind for flagging it (if it doesn't know to ignore it), but it's ultimately not wrong.

Comment: I'm also not sure where the `glibc_strcmp_x86_64_sse_4_2_bug.c:9` message comes from.

Comment: I might be inclined to report the strange code as a bug in clang anyway, or check if it's known; if nothing else it's a missed optimization.  Interestingly if the string `"four"` is replaced by something with five or more characters, the comparison is optimized out, but there's still a redundant `xor eax, eax ; test al, al, jne ...`

Comment: @NateEldredge Tends more and more to look like a buggy optimizer, indeed. So if you have an account at their bugzilla you might give it a try. It might not get seen as a bug but if we are lucky we get a bit more information. Valgrind itself might have more information (No, bug #329694 is something different, sadly) Aaaah, got it: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=340392 adding `--expensive-definedness-checks=yes` removes the error with 3.13.0. So there we are again, asking: "Who's to blame?" ;-)